Weak derivatives and function composition
I know there are lots of questions about this on this website, but usually it is for the opposite order of composition as the one I have here. Suppose $u(t,x)$ is weakly differentiable (in both arguments) on the set $(a,b) \times (c,d)$ and $f : (a,b) \times (e,f) \rightarrow (c,d) \in C^1$ and is invertible in its second argument. I want to see a rigorous proof of the fact that $g(t,x) \equiv u(t, f(t, x))$ is weakly differentiable with weak derivatives $$g_t(t,x) = u_t(t,x) + u_x(t,f(t,x)) f_t(t,x) $$ and $$g_x(t,x) = u_x(t,f(t,x))f_x(t,x) $$ where the subscripts denote the weak partial derivatives. Am I mistaken to think that one can naively apply the chain rule? When I try to prove this, I write the mapping $(t,x) \mapsto (t, f(t,x))$ is invertible so one can change variables, but I cannot get things to work. Any help would be massively appreciated.

The chain rule can be applied naively, at least we don't waste time to justify in the actual research.
But be careful that $u_x(t,f(t,x))$ is not defined if we only assume $u_x\in L^1((a,b)\times(c,d))$ and $f(t,\cdot)$ not necessarily bi-Lipschitz.
The simplest way to justify the formula (but not the most general way) is to use approximations. Let's assume $u\in W^{1,1}(Q)$ and $F:Q'\to Q$ is a bi-Lipschitz map where $Q,Q'\subset\Bbb R^2$ open, then we can find $u_j\in C^1(Q)$ such that $u_j\xrightarrow{W^{1,1}}u$. The chain rule applies to $u_j$ and you can check that both sides converges in $L^1$.
The bi-Lipschitz assumption of $F$ is used in the change of variable formula $\int_{Q'} u(F(x))\phi(x)dx=\int_Qu(y)\phi(F^{-1}(y))|\det\nabla F^{-1}(y)|dy$.
In your case $F(t,x)=(t,f(t,x))$.
If you assume $u\in W^{1,1}((a,b)\times(c,d))\cap L^\infty_x((c,d);W^{1,1}_t(a,b))$ then the bi-Lipschitz assumption can be removed. This can also be varified by the approximation method.
